# keras bidirectional layer with custom RNN Cell

Tags: keras

The following model

```
lstm_model = Sequential()
lstm_model.add(embedding)
tensor_lstm_cell = TensorLSTMCell(hidden_size=lstm_size, num_units=4)
lstm_model.add(Bidirectional(RNN(tensor_lstm_cell, return_sequences=True)))
```

throws the following error:
`ValueError: Unknown layer: TensorLSTMCell`, it seems to come from the bidirectional loading it from `config`. Im wondering how can I use the `model.add` functionality to add a custom rnn layer to the bidirectional wrapper

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `CustomObjectScope` to wrap the `Bidirectional` line so that it can recognize your custom object `TensorLSTMCell`. For example,

```py
from keras.utils.generic_utils import CustomObjectScope

class DummyLSTMCell(LSTMCell):
    pass

embedding = Embedding(10000, 32, input_shape=(None,))

lstm_model = Sequential()
lstm_model.add(embedding)
lstm_cell = DummyLSTMCell(32)
with CustomObjectScope({'DummyLSTMCell': DummyLSTMCell}):
    lstm_model.add(Bidirectional(RNN(lstm_cell, return_sequences=True)))
```

Comment: Cool!! Will this solve "pickle" or "serialize" problems when saving/loading models too?

Comment: I think pickling is a different problem. Keras models contain objects that cannot be pickled. Using `CustomObjectScope` might not help here.